# Tf command login issue

Tags: tfs, tf-cli

I am trying the [Tf command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0.aspx) and found that It will popup the form to input the username and password or you have to write the username and password after the command line, such as `/login:username=xxx,password=xxxx` for the checkout/checkin operate.
Is there any way to login TFS once and needn't login again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your credentials to Windows [Credentials Manager](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Store-passwords-certificates-and-other-credentials-for-automatic-logon) (aka Windows Vault).

[image]